# Imprimir valores grandes con formato

Tags: python, python-3.x

Como ejemplo, si tengo

```
f=10000000

print(f)

>>>1000000
```

pero lo que yo busco es que en lugar de imprimir 1000000 me imprima 1'000,000

Quisiera saber como puedo conseguir lo que busco.

Gracias

Comment: Hola Pedro, parece que lo que quieres es una especie de  separador de miles para enteros. Si es eso, ¿Podría explicar mejor el formato que quieres  y si has intentado o investigado algo?¿Por qué en un caso usas `'` y en otro `,` ? En el caso de `1000000000` que esperas conseguir `1'000,000,000` o `1,000,000,00` o `1'000'000,000`?  Es especialmente relevante esto porque un separador de miles con la coma es trivial mediante `str.format` o f-strings por ejemplo. Un saludo.

Comment: Tal vez, este artìculo te pueda servir, [Formateando números](https://www.pybonacci.org/2013/03/03/formateando-numeros/)

Answer (score 2):

Una forma de hacer la separación como lo buscas es:

```
"{:,}".format(100000)
```

> //Imprime '100,000'

Dicho métod primero va a solicitar el identificador de separador que se va a utilizar la coma en este caso y después accediendo al método format y la cantidad que deseas aplicarle el separador